# Best tools for Automated App Testing

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests

We have built a pretty complex web applications, lots of data manipulation, drag and drop, HTML5 canvases, etc. I've written lots of unit tests for some of the heavily scripted parts of the interface, but it is difficult to test the user interactions.

What are some tools you would recommend to automate many of the UI interactions? Right now we only support chrome so it has to be compatible with that. It would be great to be able to run hundreds of UI tests every night and see what impact each day's changes have had. For instance, very often a drag interaction gets messed up because the data it represents has some undefined values (usually caused by a change somewhere else), I'd love to catch these right away instead of waiting for another team member to realize them.

Thanks

Comment: maybe such a question is more suitable for Reddit rather than here. stackoverflow is not a forum, but rather a place for software specific questions and answers and not a general discussion..

Answer (score 0):

I think that your question is little bit unclear as every programmer/ tester could have different preferences so it is very hard to Choose what is best. One of the most popular ones are Selenium, Watir, Cucumber, Load UI web, web test ....
Try it yourself and choose what you want. I would use selenium but it is only my preferred solution which could or could not satisfy your needs.

By the way spring has now Spring web testing framework which I want to try myself soon also.

Edited: fixed typing errors